# Are there any ways to have multiple copies of the same building in one city?

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-gods-and-kings, civilization-5-brave-new-world

Apparently, the API method for controlling buildings takes an integer count:

`pCity:SetNumRealBuilding(GameInfoTypes["BUILDING_MONUMENT"], 1)` [(Link.)](http://modiki.civfanatics.com/index.php?title=City.SetNumRealBuilding_%28Civ5_API%29)

This [seems to get used with values greater than `1` by mods](https://forums.civfanatics.com/threads/how-to-add-free-happiness-to-a-player-by-lua-event.429585/) that change happiness in an AI-compatible way by [adding multiple copies of a dummy building](https://forums.civfanatics.com/threads/problem-with-dummy-happiness-buildings.653771/) into cities, so multiple copies of buildings are supported by the game.

**Are there any situations in the base game and official DLC that will cause more than one copy of the same building to become present in a city?** Are there any stock buildings that have the "NoLimit" flag set to enable this? The existence of the building doesn't necessarily have to be exposed in the GUI.